# Node/Express.js request handling with different files

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

//server.js

```
app.use('/shelf', require('./books').middleware);
```

//books.js

```
var app = new express.Router();

app.post('/books' , function (req, res) {
console.log('here');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is what i did so far; my server runs under server.js, and when i make a '/shelf/books' request, it first goes to server.js and then to the books.js file and logs 'here'. but i want to add a request handler(a different file, handler.js i.e) where i want to to validate if the post param is a number and than redirect it to books.js if it is.

Answer (score 0):

**How about this?**

//handler.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    req.check_result = /\d+/.test(req.body.yourfield); 
};
```

// book.js

```
app.post('/books' , function (req, res) {
    if(req.check_result) {
        // your code
    } else {
        // your code
    }
});
```

// server.js

```
app.use('/shelf', require('./handler'));
app.use('/shelf', require('./books').middleware);
```

Comment: i want to make the validation in a different file and then continue with the routing. so after server.js i want to be able to check in handler.js and then continue. server->handler->books

Comment: i also want to be able to post /shelf and log something for example, but now it responses cannot /post shelf

Comment: remove '/shelf' from app.use, then app.post('/shelf', ...); app.post('/shelf/:book', ...);

Answer (score 0):

**`app.js`**

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());

app.use(require('./handler').middleware);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**`handler.js`**

```
var express = require('express')
var books = require('./books')

var router = new express.Router();

router.get('/shelf/:book_id', function(req, res){
  var onlyNumbers =req.param('book_id').match(/^\d+$/)
  if (onlyNumbers){
    var parsedNumber = parseInt(req.param('book_id'));
    if( parsedNumber ) {
      books(parsedNumber)
      console.log("Parsed number is : " + parsedNumber)
      res.end("Parsed number is : " + parsedNumber) 
    }
  }
  else {
      console.log("not a number : " + req.param('book_id')) 
      res.end("not a number : " + req.param('book_id'))
    }

  res.end('');
})

module.exports = router;
```

**`books.js`**

```
var express = require('express')

var app = new express.Router();


module.exports = function(req, res) {
  console.log("\t in books module")
};
```

Comment: instead of router.get in handler.js, how can i adopt it to a function. i want to have a function inside handler.js and pass the paramaters after validating to books, so i can make post there.